# How to find vendor and model of unknown drivers

Tags: windows, drivers, device-manager

I reinstalled windows on a new machine and the drivers are not present for the product network card.

When in device manager all I get is the question mark and I am unable to figure out the actual name of the vendor or model of the card. This is making my search to find the correct driver hard.

Anyone know how I to find out more about the hardware that does not have drivers?

Comment: Have you found the driver?

Comment: Yeah, I did with guess downloading from samsung, but I used your advice in another driver. thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Use [PCI database](http://www.pcidatabase.com/) (online website)

1. go to the device manager
2. open the properties of the unknown device
3. click on `details → Hardware IDs`
4. extract the vendor ID and the device ID like shown in the screenshot
5. search on the [PCI database](http://www.pcidatabase.com/) for the vender and database ID.
   The database is regularly updated by users. Scroll down [Intel's page](http://www.pcidatabase.com/vendor_details.php?id=1302) as an example.
   The results will show a driver name which can be googled

   [image]

---

### Use [Unknown Devices](http://www.halfdone.com/ukd/?aboutclick) (portable offline tool)

The portable tool even shows old drivers which are normally only visible if you type [`SET DEVMGR_SHOW_NONPRESENT_DEVICES=1`](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/remove-old-drivers-after-upgrading-to-new-hardware/) in an elevated CMD prompt before opening the device manager.

[image]

---

### Use [DriverIdentifier](http://driveridentifier.com/why.php) (offline tool with online database)

Install it or extract it with [UniExtract](http://www.portablefreeware.com/index.php?id=641) if you need a portable version. It will scan your drivers and compare them with its online database.

[image]

Comment: My driver hardware ID shows up as ms_ndsiwanbh and is not found on the site you recommended

Comment: @Yvette Sorry to hear that. I already had the same issue with a laptop. What exact PC/laptop and what operating system do you use? It seems to be a WAN miniport network driver

Comment: Samsung 64 bit i7 - windows 8 pro thnx Nixda

Comment: @Yvette I guess you mean a Samsung laptop. You need the exact model number. Something like "Samsung Series 9 NP900X3A-A02US". Have you tried all recommended network drivers from their [support page?](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/)

Comment: thnx for yr help nixda where would i find the model number (apart from on the bottom of the laptop- which I can't read) thnx

Answer (score 0):

I needed the sound and video drivers for a unknown motherboard of a computer I was fixing and I found a solution here: http://www.kmbytes.com/blog/2014/07/23/how-to-check-motherboard-drivers/

It is a little program that has to be installed and couple of button clicks. Worked like a charm for me. Cheers!