# How do I know the manufacturer of my netbook's wireless adapter if it is not showed on its properties?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, netbook, lenovo-laptop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finding Ethernet/Network Controller vendor/model when driver not installed](https://superuser.com/questions/526897/finding-ethernet-network-controller-vendor-model-when-driver-not-installed)

NOTE: This question has already been answered and the problem has been fixed. I don't know how to close a question so I'm just gonna put this note right here.

I just bought a Lenovo Ideapad S110 netbook running on Windows 7 ultimate (32-bit) and I'm having trouble with the wireless network controller. It doesn't have a driver installed yet. When I let windows find the driver automatically on the web, it says I should find the driver myself if I know the manufacturer. The problem is I do not know the manufacturer and when I went ahead and checked on the device's properties, it only says:

Device type: Other

Manufacturer: Unknown

Location: PCI bus 2, device 0, function 0

Device status:
The drivers for this device are not installed. (Code 28)

---

Steps taken:
I already went to the Lenovo support site and tried all of the given drivers (by trial and error) and none of them worked at all. I have contacted Lenovo and they suggested that I re-install the operating system because the OS was corrupted (the OS came with the netbook) and is causing the problem.

Is it really a problem with the OS? Or is it a hardware problem? I need your help.

(I'm not able to post a screenshot because the site says I have to earn my reputation around here :< ).

Comment: @DaveRook, Unfortunately, I can't. I do not have access to a modem/ethernet connection. I use a 3G broadband network. :(

Comment: That is correct. It is some sort of USB device that I plug into my computer. The adapters for Ethernet and Mobile Broadband are installed are not showing any problems.

Comment: Yes, the USB device does have markings. It has the name of my network carrier on the front, and the name of the manufacturer of the device on the back (Huawei) along with some numbers which I assume to be it's serial number.

But I assure you sir, this USB device and the network controller that I am talking about are completely unrelated.

Comment: Have you checked the device and vendor ID? Look this answer for explanation [how to find them](http://superuser.com/a/526905/50173)

Comment: Because that would make my post misleading, sir. The 3G USB device is not related to the wireless network controller. All in all in the device manager, 4 network controllers are displayed (Ethernet, Mobile Broadband, Bluetooth, and the unidentified network controller. The first 3 mentioned have working drivers already installed). When I typed ipconfig/all as you suggested, it only showed the first 3 (ethernet, mobile, bluetooth) which baffles me even more

Comment: Friends! I cannot fully express my unbridled joy and everlasting gratitude for your assistance! After following your suggestions, I was able to find the correct driver for the netbook, I was also able to install it correctly, and finally, I was also able to do a connection test and it was a huge success! This particular Lenovo Ideapad was using the drivers for the Thinkpad series (weird). Again thank you very much! Now, my little brother will have a fully functional laptop he can use for school. A million thanks from me and my family. To : DaveRook , nixda , WilliamHilsum

Answer (score 1):

Go back to the device properties and click on the `Details` tab.

Look for the "Hardware Ids" for the manufacturer.

Also work looking at `Compatible IDs`.

`Ven` then a number will show you the Vendor ID and `dev` will you the device ID.

You can type the values [here](http://www.pcidatabase.com/) to find out the vendor and ID of the device.

Comment: Friends! I cannot fully express my unbridled joy and everlasting gratitude for your assistance! After following your suggestions, I was able to find the correct driver for the netbook, I was also able to install it correctly, and finally, I was also able to do a connection test and it was a huge success! This particular Lenovo Ideapad was using the drivers for the Thinkpad series (weird).

Again thank you very much! Now, my little brother will have a fully functional laptop he can use for school. A million thanks from me and my family.

To : DaveRook , nixda , WilliamHilsum