# How do I get drivers Wan Miniport "windows 8"?

Tags: windows-8, drivers, hardware-failure

My computer has been working fine. I have not reinstalled or altered windows.

I have an error on my Wan Miniport.

> There is a problem with the driver for WAN miniport (Network Monitor) #2. Reinstalling the driver might fix the problem.

//and this message

> This device is not working properly because Windows cannot load the
>   drivers required for this device. (Code 31)

The trouble shooter doesn't work, it just says it's not fixed.

> Wan Miniport (Network Monitor) #2 has driver problem   Not fixed

I cannot uninstall this through the device manager. I click ok on uninstall and it does nothing.

I have searched the internet and cannot find an answer, without going into the registry. This I am reluctant to do, unless it is upon advice of a trustworthy source.

There is also an option to Add Legacy Hardware, but I do not have enough knowledge to venture into this, without advice.

I use Avast, and have a 64 bit operating system. I mention this, as it has been aggressive with removing executable files and blocking things.

The hardware ID is ms_ndiswanbh.

This question has been closed and marked as a duplicate:

[How to find vendor and model of unknown drivers](https://superuser.com/questions/526897/finding-ethernet-network-controller-vendor-model-when-driver-not-installed)

This question asks about installing windows on a new machine. There are no drivers present. In my question, I have drivers, but the troubleshooter suggests reinstalling them, and I have not been able to figure out how to do this.

> I reinstalled windows on a new machine and the drivers are not present
>   for the product network card. When in device manager all I get is the
>   question mark and am unable to figure out the actual name of the
>   vendor/model of the card making my search to find the correct drivers
>   hard. Anyone know how I can find out more about the hardware that does
>   not have drivers?

The answer to this question does not solve my problem.

Comment: @Karan I didn't change my windows installation - it was working fine, and now it's not. NOT a duplicate

Comment: Is there an option to rollback drivers for the device?

Comment: @Karan no ther isn't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a detailed explanation on a fix in the article [Broken WAN Miniports](https://oyam.ca/blog/2011/11/windows-miniports/).
I suggest very carefully reading that article, for below I only give a short summary.

**Uninstall the non-working miniport**

1. In Device Manager, right-click on the non-working miniport, choose `Update Driver`.
2. Choose `Browse my computer`.
3. In the next window, choose `Let me pick driver from a list`.
4. Uncheck `Show compatible hardware`. From the `Manufacturer` list, choose `Microsoft`, and from the `Network Adapter` list, choose `MAC Bridge Miniport`. (It can be any device the user is allowed to uninstall.)
5. Back in the device manager, delete the device that just turned into a `MAC Bridge Miniport`.
6. Reboot.

**Reinstall the miniports**

1. Get devcon.exe. Remember that a 32-bit version won't work on 64-bit systems. Getting the 64-bit version is [described here](http://techlikes.com/2010/09/25/devcon-problem-in-windows-7-solved.html).
2. Go to command prompt run as administrator and go to the directory where you extracted devcon.exe
3. The above article describes how to install many types of miniports,
   but I believe that you only need to install the Network Monitor:

`devcon.exe install c:\Windows\inf\netrasa.inf MS_NdisWanBh`

If running the command reports "driver install" failure, don’t pay it attention.
4. Reboot.

**Safety notes**

Before starting these manipulations, take backups of all your data.
Then create a system restore point, so in case of a problem you could rollback
Windows to its actual state.

Ensure also that the .inf file `C:\Windows\inf\netrasa.inf` does in fact exist.

If this doesn't work for some reason,
an alternative approach is described in the article
[Re-installing WAN miniport devices](https://web.archive.org/web/20200807172058/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/BrentCaskey/archive/2011/06/09/re-installing-wan-miniport-devices.aspx),
that does however require registry work.

Comment: Thank You!
I couldn't figure why I cannot connect to internet (ADSL) and notices that I have many errors in Device Manager (pptp, pppoe, ikev2, l2tp). I reinstalled all and everything works.
I didn't had 'MAC Bridge Miniport' so I used 'generic mobile broadband adapter' to uninstall these miniports.

Answer (score -1):

just visit Microsoft official [website](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/mats/hardware_device_problems)    and run the diagnostic. It will definitely work Which will does you the job.From the official website

What it fixes

```
When you install a hardware device, it is not detected
Determine if your audio device is plugged in
Driver updates aren't automatically installed by Windows Update
You receive one of the following errors:
Your is currently disabled or turned off in Windows
Your has a driver problem and needs to be reinstalled
Windows has detected a problem with your , it is not working properly
There is no driver installed for your Machine
```