# Find unknown device vendor info (so I can locate drivers)

Tags: windows-10, device-manager

I'm trying to connect to a payment terminal to upload the program. But googling for the driver didn't provide any answers.

The device:

- Name: PAX
- Model: s58

I want to connect via USB and make a connection.

In Windows I see 1 "unknown device" and 1 "livio_connect" for which I/it can't find drivers.

Usually I could find the vendor and device ID by checking:

Properties -> Details -> Device instance id

Here I could read which vendor and device so I could search easier.

Where is this option in Windows 10?

**Update**

According to some comments I started wondering if the device id and or vendor id could/would change when not compatible (but I wouldn't think so).

Comment: It is hidden in the same place it always has, Device Manager, is a great way to get to it.

Comment: Already searched there. Can't find device instance id's

Comment: There are also numerous tools which display information on all USB devices connected to your system, those tools based on the generic tool developed by Microsoft, could also provide the same information.  [The information is still located in the same place though](http://superuser.com/questions/526897/how-to-find-vendor-and-model-of-unknown-drivers?rq=1)

Comment: @davejal Is that device compatible with Windows 10 ?

Comment: Not sure if it's compatible. There isn't much info on the internet. So that's what I'm trying to find out. It's also the first time I'm using it, so I don't have the old drivers to test. The vendor id would be 1234 and the device id 0101. But I can't find info on either.

Comment: @davejal **Your post is about how to find Vendor ID of an unknown device and turns out you already know it !!!!!!** Your actual question should be something like is this device compatible with windows 10 or where to find driver for windows 10 for XYZ device.

Comment: A USB device can be configured in a such a way, where the Vendor ID and Device ID can be anything the manufacture wants it to be, an operating system trusts this information to be correct, a value of `1234` is extremely suspect to me.

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like - The question of "where to find a device driver for this specific device" is not a question that should be at Superuser.  The question of if a device is supported on Windows 10 is acceptable, but not really that helpful, from a community perspective.

Comment: @the_it_guy_you_don't_like. See ramhound's comment, I was thinking the same. And it's not 'device instance id', which I'm used to. So still I'm not sure if that's correct or not.

Comment: There is not over internet for this device. However I could track down the manufacturer site...http://www.pax.com.cn/Upload/%E7%99%BE%E5%AF%8C%E4%BA%A7%E5%93%81/Countertop/S58_ENG-13432465407.pdf Try contact them, see if it helps

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like, thanks I will contact them.

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvote?

Comment: @davejal - The possible reasons have already been explained.  As with any vote, the specific reason for the vote is not known, unless the person who issued the vote wants to share the reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Device Instance Path", is what you need on Windows 10 to locate the device instance ID.

1. Right-click the device
2. select properties
3. click on the Details tab
4. select "Device Instance Path" from the drop down list

I tried searching for the drivers too, but no joy, sorry :(

Comment: this is where I got the info from, but as already commented it seems weird to have a vendor id of 1234 and an devive id of 0101.

Comment: Check this, I googled "windows 10 vendor ID 1234", and got: http://pcidatabase.com/vendors.php?sort=id

Comment: Hmm, not easy spacing out your text here in the comment!  Anyway, seach for 1234 (CTRL+F in Chrome) in that list on that page. You'll find "0x1234 Technical Corp"

Comment: Yes I found it, but [this](http://pcidatabase.com/search.php?device_search_str=0x0101) you see there's no vendor with that id with an device id of 0101.

Comment: That is very odd, and also odd that the company (PAX) does not seem to provide downloadable drivers for any of their products. If I were you, the next step I'd take would be to contact PAX's technical support. This is looking like a banging your head on a brick wall situation, otherwise :(

Comment: Already mailed them. No answer -> Yet. Maybe because of the end of the year ...???

Comment: Distinct possibility :) Okay, there appears to be more than one PAX site (different areas of the world?), you could try as many as you can find - http://www.paxsz.com/ http://paxtechnology.us/  - and perhaps anyone you know who has a PAX? <-- would've done that already!!!

Comment: They still haven't replied, so I'm still stuck